# Emacs not recognizing its own scripts in /emacs/lisp/

Tags: emacs

I'm very new to emacs and I'm using version 23.2 on Windows. I'm trying to get CEDET working, but when I require it in .emacs it fails to find the file:

```
File error: Cannot open load file
```

I was able to get cedet working by loading it manually with:

```
 (load "C:/emacs/lisp/cedet/cedet.el")
```

But I still can't require other files from cedet like semantic-gcc or semantic-ia.

Here's my .emacs file:

```
(load "C:/emacs/lisp/cedet/cedet.el")
(global-ede-mode t)
(semantic-mode 1)
;(semantic-load-enable-excessive-code-helpers)
(require 'semantic-ia)
(require 'semantic-gcc)
```

It's like emacs isn't looking for these files in its own path, and I did try

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/emacs/lisp/cedet")
```

With a lot of other variations but none worked.

Comment: Have you had a look at http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to find the reason that cedet won't load with a simple `(require 'cedet)`.

1. Is Emacs installed at `c:\emacs`? (ie the emacs.exe you are running is c:\emacs\bin\emacs.exe)
2. Is something setting `EMACSLOADPATH` externally from Emacs (your environment, or in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` `/Software/GNU/Emacs`?
3. Is there another installation of an older version of CEDET on your load path?
4. Has `c:\emacs\lisp\subdirs.el` been edited to remove the cedet subdirectory?

Once you've solved that, note that the paths were changed when CEDET was merged into Emacs to accommodate old systems that have limitations on file name lengths.  But at the same time, the autoloads were improved, so you shouldn't need to explicitly require those files any more.  If you still do, the following should work:

```
(require 'semantic/ia)
(require 'semantic/bovine/gcc)
```