# include ~/.emacs.d/emacs-xcode and require 'xcode gives "Cannot open load file, xcode"

Tags: xcode, emacs

I'd like to use Emacs (version 23.4.1) on OS X (version 10.6.8) to replace Xcode (version 4.2) as my text editor.

I've copied `emacs-xcode.el` from https://github.com/senny/emacs-xcode to my local directory `~/.emacs.d/emacs-xcode/emacs-xcode.el`

In `.emacs`, I have

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/emacs-xcode/"))
(require 'xcode)
```

When I run Emacs, it gives a warning:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/thunderrabbit/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, xcode
```

In `.emacs`, I have also tried

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/emacs-xcode/emacs-xcode.el"))
(require 'xcode)
```

For those more familiar with Emacs than xcode, at the very end of `~/.emacs.d/emacs-xcode/emacs-xcode.el` is the line

```
(provide 'xcode)
```

Which I assume is paired with the `(require 'xcode)` in `.emacs`

EDIT:  I added `(require 'monkey)` at the end of `emacs-xcode.el` and Emacs did *not* complain about it not being able to load monkey.  So it appears that `emacs-xcode.el` is not being loaded at all.

`emacs-xcode.el` is owned by me with permissions 644.  Its parent directories are owned by me with permissions 755.

Why isn't it being opened?

N.B. I cut-n-pasted the file names, so I'm sure they are spelled correctly.

Comment: Back-quoting the symbol in your `provide` statement is unusual -- it shouldn't cause a problem, but `(provide 'xcode)` would be more normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the name of the file with the `provide` statement is not the same as the symbol name in the `require` statement, and therefore Emacs does not know which file to look in.

You can either rename the library `xcode.el`, or else require it with an explicit filename:

```el
(require 'xcode "emacs-xcode")
```

Comment: Thank you!   I thought I had tried that fix in one of my variants, but apparently not!

Answer (score 0):

I found a clue here [Emacs not recognizing its own scripts in /emacs/lisp/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344542/emacs-not-recognizing-its-own-scripts-in-emacs-lisp)

And I've solved it by adding `(load "emacs-xcode.el")` to my `.emacs`

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/emacs-xcode/"))
(load "emacs-xcode.el")
(require 'xcode)
```

I'll not select my answer for a while in case anyone else has a better solution.